# Flutter Expand Column's children horizontally to the size of the largest children

Tags: flutter, layout

I have a column inside a `Positioned` (within a `Stack`), meaning that I cannot use any Expanded widget as, as far as I know the positioned does not provide any constraints meaning.
In particular, I am trying to align 2 widgets in a column to the left and to the right.
But if I put a row inside a column, it gets shrunken to the size of the smallest children inside it, like the image, while it should expand to the size of the largest children.

[image]

This is the code for the above picture:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      top: 20,
      left: 20,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text("Long Widget Title"),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: [const Text("Left Text")],
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: [const Text("Right Text")],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

This is the layout I am trying to obtain, with its behaviour in different situations:

[image]

I think it might be obtainable with the current setup if there was a way to stretch each row (including the title) to the size of the widest child. Is that possible?

Comment: Can you add your expected image result

Comment: I added it along with some examples of the layout in different situations.

Comment: Have you tried the property `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` for the column? That should force every child of your coulmn to use the full width

Comment: If I do that, I get an error as the Positioned does not provide any constraints on the width and thus it will just expand indefinitely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily achive that layout using `IntrinsicWidth` https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicWidth-class.html

> A widget that sizes its child to the child's maximum intrinsic width.

Just put the widget before your Container like below :

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      top: 20,
      left: 20,
      child: IntrinsicWidth(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                const Text("Long Widget Title"),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        child: const Text("Left Text"),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const Expanded(child: SizedBox.shrink()),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: [
                    const Expanded(child: SizedBox.shrink()),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        child: const Text("Right Text"),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Check the dartpad version here https://dartpad.dev/?id=2b07ca68f1897d9868400858b9ca169b

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      top: 20,
      left: 20,
      child: Container(
       width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text("Long Widget Title"),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          Row(
           mainAxisAlignment : MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children:[
              Container(color: Colors.red, child: Text("title 1 - left text")),
            ]
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          Row(
           mainAxisAlignment : MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children:[
              Container(color: Colors.red, child: Text("title 2 - right text")),
            ]
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the row just shrinks to the size of the children meaning that they are positioned in the center. The image I produced is using this exact layout.

Comment: Please add width for the container. Edited the answer

Comment: That could solve it, but my problem is that in this way it will just fill out all the available space instead of being constrained to the minimum space needed.

Comment: if you add a right to the positioned you will see that it will take the full space. We are forcing it to use the min size possible. It won't take the child's width in this case.

Comment: My question was that, if it is possible to make a column's children take the maximum amount of space they can take without expanding the column to infinity.

Comment: No i don't think it's possible

Comment: It is possible, check my answer

Answer (score 0):

- 

```
*Row(
       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          Text("Left Text"),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          Text("right Text"),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),*
```

- 

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I initially implemented it like this but with this if I only have left side titles, It would place them in the center and left side and right side titles would be placed at the same level. I added examples to the question, containing the behaviour I'm trying to achieve in those different situations.